# Cross compiled gcc fails with 'unrecognised emulation mode: -dynamic-linker'

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling, ld

I got a gcc binary cross compiled with:

```
Configured with: /home/fornwall/termux/gcc/src/configure 
-disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
--disable-rpath --disable-rpath-hack --host=i686-linux-android
--enable-languages=c,c++ --with-system-zlib
--disable-multilib --disable-lto --with-gmp=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
--with-mpfr=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr --with-mpc=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
--with-stage1-ldflags=-specs=/home/fornwall/dc/termux.spec
--with-arch=i686 --with-tune=atom--with-fpmath=sse
--disable-nls --enable-shared --disable-static
--libexecdir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec
```

When compiling a C program, `gcc test.c`, I get:

```
ld: unrecognised emulation mode: -dynamic-linker
Supported emulations: elf_i386 i386linux elf32_x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

due to the following `collect2` call (as told by `gcc -v test.c`) missing an argument to the `-m` flag:

```
COMPILER_PATH=. LIBRARY_PATH=.
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=atom' '-march=i686'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.3/collect2
-m -dynamic-linker
-pie /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.3/../../../crtbegin_dynamic.o
-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.3
-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.3/../../..
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp//ccxXWQIJ.o
-lgcc -lc -ldl -lgcc
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.3/../../../crtend_android.o
```

Where is the the problem? Is `--host=i686-linux-android` an incorrect host?

Comment: --host options means that you are going to use compiler on `HOST` machine , in your case it means that you are going to use compiler on `Android`, for me it's  sounds wired.  I suppose you have to use --target options , for using your `GCC` compiler on your machine and be able to compiler code for `android` devices. From GNU docs: `There are three system names that the build knows about: the machine you are building on (build), the machine that you are building for (host), and the machine that GCC will produce code for (target). `

Comment: It's actually supposed to run on `Android` :) - http://termux.com/

Comment: Then you may try to build gcc `statically`. And it will work, Or you have to fix `gcc`, cause as far as i know on android dynamic linker calls `linker` instead of `ld` you can find it here `/system/linker`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, building gcc statically does not change how it calls `collect2`, so same problem there.

Comment: Or you may rebuilt `binutils` :)